# slideToggle links independently

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Been trying to get slideToggle to close if already opened aka not reopen if already open. Searched all over for this function but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

jQuery

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".shareLink").click(function(){
$(".hideShare").hide();
  $("#"+$(this).attr('id')+'Box').slideToggle();
  return false;
  });

});
</script>
```

heres a link to it
http://digitalzu.net/jquery.html

Comment: slideToggle does just as it says, it toggles the current state. It shouldn't reopen if already open. Followed your link, but don't understand what doesn't work. Seems to work correctly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not working because you are hiding all the `hideShare` elements which includes the current box also so it just toggles.

Try this, it will only hide its `siblings`.

```
 $(".shareLink").unbind().click(function(){
       $("#"+$(this).attr('id')+'Box')
       .siblings('.hideShare')
       .slideUp()
       .end()
       .slideToggle();

       return false;
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d97qa/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var $el = $("#"+$(this).attr('id')+'Box');

if($el.is(":hidden")){
    $(".hideShare").hide();
    $el.slideDown();
}
```

You're hiding everything and then sliding down the one element.  The problem is that you are doing this even if the element is already visible.  Instead, make sure that it is not already visible, if it is, do nothing.